# Build a Queue with a limitation of Array of size 5 - but queue can grow

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Question: Build a queue class with the enqueue and dequeue methods. However, the language you are using has a bug which does not allow arrays to store more than 5 elements, how would you build that?

I wrote the below code and I was rejected, curious to understand what is the issue and why I was rejected, fyi - this is in technical phone screen.

```
static LinkedList<Queue<Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Queue<Integer>>();

public static void enQueue(Integer element){

    //iterating the linkedlist....
    while(true){ //todo
        Queue<Integer> curr;
        if(list.size() > 0)
            curr = list.getLast();
        else{
            curr = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            list.add(curr);
        }
        if(curr.size() < 5){
            curr.add(element);
            System.out.println("enqueued:" + element);
            break;
        } else{
            Queue<Integer> newQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            newQueue.add(element);
            list.add(newQueue); //adding the new Queue of size(5) to the list
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static Integer deQueue(){
    LinkedList<Queue<Integer>> node = list;
    if(!isEmpty()){
        Integer retValue = 0;
        while(list.size() > 0){
            Queue<Integer> q = node.getFirst();
            if(!q.isEmpty()){
                retValue =  q.poll();
                break;
            }else{
                node.removeFirst();
            }
        }
        return retValue;
    }else{
        System.out.println("No such element found");
        return -1; //throw new NoSuchElementException("no element found");
    }
}

public static boolean isEmpty(){
    return list.size() == 0;
}
```

Comment: How about implementing the queue itself as a linked list? That is, forget about arrays altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You were rejected, because:

- you assumed a pre-existing Queue class, which is what you were supposed to implement.
- you used a LinkedList, which already implements a queue-like interface, instead of actually implementing a queue.
- You used the LinkedList badly -- there is no reason for any kind of loop at all.  You could have just had your enQueue and deQueue call LinkedList.add()  LinkedList.pollFirst()

The interviewer really wanted you to actually implement a queue.  The array limitation is to force you to use a linked implementation, and the interviewer wanted to see you maintain the links properly.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your reply, I agree that I don't need a loop.. but its ok to use java collections, the question is not to write my own queue, only restriction is array cannot have size more than 5.. i think i used while(true) and break which is very bad, and i used this in an hurry where I was trying to execute my code in rush..

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is to check on your implementation of queue data structure  with arrays, which cannot be more than size of 5.

I would have something like

```
Class Queue {

int[][] data;
int maxSize = 25; //5 * 5
int[] front;
int[] rear;

Enqeue(int element) {
   //Check for queue full
   //Increment front last index, if it crosses 5. Increment previous index
   //Use the front index identify data element
   //Put the data
}

Dequeue() {
   //Check for queue empty

   //Use the rear index identify data element
   //get the data
   //Increment rear last index, if it crosses 5. Increment previous index
   //Return the data

}



}
```

The queue size can be easily scaled to big numbers.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It's unlikely that the interviewer would have been OK with the size limitation.

Comment: Any queue or data structure will have a upper bound. That's why we have "queue full" exceptions. I guess the interviewer is trying to see how you are overcoming the limitation. You can easily change the above thing for 125, 625,.. just add another dimension in data, front and rear pointers.

Comment: No, there is no reason to have any such upper bound.  For example, a LinkedList doesn't have any such upper bound, and contains no arrays with more than 5 elements.

Comment: Agree on the linked list implementation has no upper bound. By you may want to implement the 'queue full' case also. may be millions. Looks like linked list based implementation is clean solution for this case.

Comment: Thanks Arun for your suggestion, but we cannot have max size for the queue.. yes linked list is one of the option, to link the 5-element array